# Setting Static IP on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+

Tags: pi-3, wifi

I'm trying to set a Static IP for my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ and I have been referring to the following documentation:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/networking-lessons/rpi-static-ip-address/

I want to have a static IP for my Pi when I connect it via a WiFi or a LAN cable. I basically want both the options to have the same Static IP. What I do not understand is the following:

In my /etc/dhcpcd.conf, I see some IPV6 configurations like this:

```
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
#static ip6_address=bc62:31d6:abzu:b92a::ee/53
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 bc62:31d6:abzu:b92a::1
```

Can I completely remove the ip6_address? In the documentation link that I posted above, there is something related to wlan0 - Is this the setting related to WiFi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really MUST [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697) shows how to do it.

You CAN NOT set 2 interfaces to have the same address. Again if you **REALLY** want to use the same static IP address for interfaces if only 1 is connected you can use a fallback See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) but this is not a great idea - you would **NEED** to stop WiFi from connecting.

I feel obliged to point out that **there is no NEED to set static IP addresses** - I haven't done this since 1980, unless configuring a DHCP server. I don't know what the IP of my 7 Pi or 3 Macs or other devices are, and don't care - I access them by name, and make the routers do their job!

You can remove `ip6` if you aren't using them - there is even less need for static ip6 addresses

Comment: The plan is for me to set up a Kubernetes cluster on my RasPi's. I will be having 7 of them booted up and I think from an operation point of view, I thought it might make sense to have a static ip for all of them. Could you please justify why there is no need for a static ip? I appreciate your comments!

Comment: There are several reasons. 1. the most important if you ever need to use a different network (at a different place - I take my Pi to friends houses, or just change ISP) you have to change everything. 2. I have a fist full of SD Cards - I can plug any one into any Pi, copy them etc, which is difficult if each is set to a static IP. If you are running a cluster that is never going to move this may be one of the few valid exceptions.

Comment: I have just worked on too many networks over the years, and people who try to pick an IP just create problems - virtually all networks have a DHCP server, and this can be configured to always give the same IP to specified MAC.

Comment: Is there a way to ssh using the host name? I don't want to set a static ip, but I would like to ssh using the hostname? I guess I could do this or?

Comment: I did just change the hostname and I can now ssh into my pi using pi@myhostname.local

Comment: To me this way of logging into the pi via ssh is more than enough. I can now configure 7 of them and give them names accordingly such that I don't have to care about the ip addresses anymore! Hence I do not need to assign a static ip address anymore!

Comment: Bravo! @Milliways is correct; DHCP is a time-saver, and makes more sense on **MOST** networks. And wrt your other question: "Could you please justify why there is no need for a static ip?", the short answer is **MAC address**; that's what's used to communicate in your Kubernetes cluster, and in fact on any IP network.

Comment: @Milliways - You are categorically wrong in stating that "there is no NEED to set static IP addresses". If you are running in environments where there is no DHCP server, then a static IP is required.